Android SharedPreferences: Data accessible but shared_prefs folder missing
I'm using SharedPreferences in my Android application to store information. I can successfully read and retrieve data using SharedPreferences. However, when I access the /data/data/myapplication/* directory with root privileges, I can't find the shared_prefs folder.
Here's what I've done so far:

Implemented SharedPreferences in my app to store and retrieve data.
Verified that the data is being saved and can be read within the app.
Accessed the /data/data/myapplication/* directory using root privileges.
Searched for the shared_prefs folder, but it's not there.

My questions are:

Where are my SharedPreferences being stored if not in the shared_prefs folder?
Is there a reason why the shared_prefs folder might not be visible even with root access?
Are there any specific Android versions or devices where the storage location for SharedPreferences might be different?ent?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

what your android version?

I use android 9 and this is my build.gradle: compileSdk 34,  targetSdk 23,  minSdk 17

I just discovered another strange thing: I used the pm clear command to delete my application but Sharedprefs is still there even though the Shared_prefs folder does not exist?

I'm late， I think  SharedPreferences  still save in /data/data/myapplication/shared_prefs ，but your system not sousrport you visit it.you can visit it in your app or use adb shell(cd  /data/data/myapplication/shared_prefs and ls)
